# how to replace a placeholders in another file in linux

Tags: c, linux, templates

I have searched for that several times but I have no obvious answer

I want to make a C function that takes a variable as an argument and then uses that argument to replace a placeholder in another template file  in the form like that

Port %PORT%

I need that when that function get called the %PORT% is replaced with the parameter being passed  ( this placeholder is in another file )

any hint for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using `sed`?  It is available on most linux systems, you should be able to accomplish what you want using this examples, which reads template file tmpl.txt and creates a file called specific.txt where the value %Port% is replaced with a 4242 which was saved in a variable PVAR:
tmpl.txt

```
Port %PORT%
```

code:

```
PVAR=4242
sed "s/%PORT%/$PVAR/" tmpl.txt > p4242.txt
```

p4242.txt:

```
Port 4242
```

Comment: great thanks 
but I need to make a C function that uses the "sed" command 
how can I do that ?

something like that 

void func(int PVAR){
// do the same stuff as the sed command

}

Comment: Sorry I think I may have misunderstood the question a bit when I was posting the answer.  I will update the answer with a C solution, out of curiosity does the template file contain a single token value pair or are there several tokens?  Does the solution have to be C based or would C++ be acceptable as well?

Comment: never mind .... C solution is better but I have no problem with C++ at all ... and they are several tokens ... thanks again !

Comment: C++ would allow for the convenient use of the `pair<...>` template to store token-value pairs.  From a convenience and simplicity of coding standpoint it seems like C++ would allow a more elegant solution, but that is somewhat subjective.  I will work on both C and C++ solutions and make an update later today or tomorrow.